# CentOS - cron service dies every few days

Tags: centos, cron, troubleshooting

I am on using CentOS 6.7 server and every few days my cron service dies.

I've tried checking: `cat /var/log/messages | grep cron` but there was nothing relevant.

How can I check what's killing the service?

Comment: Server or Client?

Comment: @FarazX Server. Updated question.

Comment: So it is up 24/7 ?

Comment: @FarazX Yes it is

Comment: As you know, in this situation only root can kill the process, not any normal user. Have you checked for commands with SUID bit set? This is not a clear question, we need more information to investigate the problem.

Comment: @FarazX I have a very limited Linux experience so I am not sure what you mean by *commands with SUID bit set*... I can provide any logs that are relevant if it helps to debug the issue.

Comment: Check with your admin, whether is there any password change policy enabled after certain period..which may match with your cron failure until you change the password.. I had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue turned out my own bug - I've made a process that goes up every 15 minutes. Unfortunately, the process when closed, would leave his child processes up and I've collected thousands of such processes every few days.

Every now and then CentOS would run out of memory and kill some process to get more memory. It seems that cron was killed due to that reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set your cron job in a right manner and syntax, you should check for **security holes** since in this situation only the user root can do the kill, not any normal user. Everything depends on what you have set and how you've done it, plus system configurations and users' privileges.

I recommend you read cron and crontab manual page by running `man cron` and `man crontab`, and also check your `/etc/crontab`.

For checking security holes, the first thing you can do is to check for commands with SUID bit set, you can learn about [Permissions with SUID SGID and Sticky bits from this article on Oracle System Administration Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html). You can see permissions by using `ls -l`. Check your commands and see if they have these bits on or not.

You should also check `/etc/sudoers` and see that which users have the ability to run commands with `sudo` privilege without needing root user's password.

I hope this can help.

Comment: So you suspect it is killed off by another user? I originally thought cron service simply crashes.

Comment: If someone has sudo privilege. yes it is possible. The problem may have too many difference reasons, you should check your system and figure out what the main reason is.

Comment: @VitalyB BTW, when a cron job crash, it will leave some error messages in the log.